Looking for equality between two multisets
Consider the following two infinite multisets:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A}&:=\{n^2+nm+m^2: \, n, m\in\mathbb{Z}\}, \\
\mathcal{B}&:=\{n^2+3m^2: \, n, m\in \mathbb{Z}\} \,\cup \,
\{n^2+3m^2 + n+3m + 1: \, n, m \in \mathbb{Z}\}.
\end{align*}

QUESTION. Can you prove equality of these two multisets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}\,$?

I'm stating the problem this way but the original set up was an attempt to proving equality of Jacobi theta products:
$$\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2+nm+m^2}
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{3m^2}+ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{(n+\frac12)^2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{3(m+\frac12)^2}$$
but things did not work out for me.

So... you have $3$ quadratic forms and you are asking if they represent the same set of integers in the same way? If so,  there's a whole theory of quadratic forms out there.

If you know nothing about quadratic forms, there's always the brute force approach to establish the bijection. Split up $A$ according to the parity of $(n, m)$:

$(2a)^2 + (2a)(2b) + (2b)^2 = (2a+b)^2 + 3b^2:$ Corresponds to $B$ first set  where the terms have the same parity.

$(2a+1)^2 + (2a+1)(2b) + (2b)^2 = (2a+b+1)^2 + 3b^2: $  Corresponds to $B$ first set where the terms have different parity.

$(2a)^2 + (2a)(2b+1) + (2b)^2 =  ( 2a+b)^2 + 3b^2 + (2a+b) + 3b + 1:$ Corresponds to $B$ seconds set  where the terms have the same parity.

$(2a+1)^2 + (2a+1)(2b+1)+(2b+1)^2 = (2a+b+1)^2 +3b^2 + (2a+b+1) +3b + 1:$   Corresponds to $B$ second set where the terms have different parity.


